# How mongos instance choose config server?

Tags: mongodb, config

I'm wondering whether there is a way which can set priority to the three config servers for all mongos instances.

Because We deploy mongo clusters cross IDC, two of the config servers on the main one and another on the other. We want mongos to access the two first, and the last one is for hot backups.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't believe there is a way, I believe it works by latency, just picks the closest based on that

Answer (score 0):

The config server that is listed first in the string of three is the one that will be used by all `mongos` instances.  If you have one that you would prefer be used, list it first when you launch `mongos` processes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That will be a great help for me!